# Need to convert Text field to Varchar temporarily so that I can pass to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I am using a SQL 2000 database.

I am working with a database in which I cannot change the types on the tables, or the stored procedures. One of the stored procedures I need to call expects a parameter of 'text'. I can get to the text field, but I am unable to figure out who to store that in a variable or any other way to pass it into the stored procedure?

If I try and create a text variable, SQL won't let me - if I convert it to varchar I only get the first character from the text field.

Any tricks to get around this much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Declare the variable of type `varchar(8000)`

```
declare @v varchar(8000)
SET @v = (SELECT CAST(textcol as varchar(8000)) FROM yourtable WHERE ....)
```

Obviously it might still be truncated but not at 1 character.

Comment: Hello, I updated my question to show that I'm using SQL 2000.

Comment: You'll have to use `varchar(8000)` or `nvarchar(4000)` then. Obviously it might be truncated but not at 1 character.

Comment: Most of these text fields contain way more than 8000 - this is definitely of excellent help though.

Comment: Hmm, Not sure if there is any way around this actually.

Comment: In other areas within the existing stored procedures looks like TextPtr() and UPDATETEXT are being used so I may have to figure out those.

Comment: Can you change the stored procedure so that it is responsible for retrieving the `text` data rather than passing it in? What does it do with it anyway? Insert it into another row?

Comment: That's a good suggestion, will try that. The procedure just updates the text value with what is passed in, but it normally gets a text value passed in - i think the front end application is doing the conversion.

Comment: If you really want a solution - support for more than 8000 characters and being able to pass to stored proc - you'll have to upgrade to SQL Server 2005 or newer which supports `VARCHAR(MAX)` which can hold up to 2 GByte of textual data. SQL Server 2000 doesn't offer any useable solution for this, sorry....