# SQLite DB Browser: invalid operand for regexp

Tags: regex, sqlite

I used DB Browser for SQLite version 3.6.0; SQLite Version 3.8.9.
This application already supports Regular Expression out of box [(sqlitebrowser)](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/wiki/Regular-Expressions). I can use `regexp` on column `brand` but failed on column `revision`;

For example

```
SELECT brand,revision FROM TDevice where TDevice.brand regexp '^ASUS$'
```

and the result is `114 Rows returned from: SELECT brand,revision FROM TDevice WHERE TDevice.brand regexp '^ASUS$'; (took 51ms)`

However, if `regexp` is applied on different column, then I get the error

```
SELECT brand,revision FROM TDevice WHERE TDevice.revision regexp '^ASUS$';
```

and the error message is `invalid operand: SELECT brand,revision FROM TDevice WHERE TDevice.revision regexp '^ASUS$';`

Both brand and revision are of TEXT type. The table creation schema is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `TDevice` (
`id`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
`brand` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`model` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`revision`  TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Both brand and revision are of TEXT type. The table creation schema is as below:

No They are different see your table description correctly if you change the `TEXT` to `varchar` it will work fine.

Or I will check and inform you how to use `regex` or can we use `regex` with `TEXT` datatype.

or you can convert(CAST) your `TEXT`  to varchar and can perform the match operations

See this post for how to CAST TEXT into varchar
[Need to convert Text field to Varchar temporarily so that I can pass to a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360150/need-to-convert-text-field-to-varchar-temporarily-so-that-i-can-pass-to-a-stored)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `brand` and `revision` is that `brand` cannot accept NULL text. After I fill the `revision` with empty string '':

```
UPDATE TDevice SET revision='' WHERE revision IS NULL
```

, this `invalid operand` error is resolved.