# REGEXP and SQLITE

Tags: regex, sqlite

Anyone have a suggestion how I might be able to write a REGEXP in SQLITE that uses the same functionality as `\K` in say Teradata.

Example:

```
text = "height"=>"5","xxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Regexp:

```
SELECT * FROM xxxxx where xxxxx = 'xxxxxxx'and xxxxxx 
where REGEXP '"height".+?"\K\d+'
```

This returns the integer 5.

This regepx works fine in Teradata but not SQLITE.
I am using  DB Browser (SQLite)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sqlite doesn't have built-in support for regular expressions. You have to use an extension module that provides the syntax you need. (I have a few I'm working on for different RE engines, but nothing really production ready yet).

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I use DB Browser (SQLite) which allows me to run REGEXP.

Comment: Perhaps use a capturing group `"height".+?"(\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/rihFjd/1

Comment: This returns an invalid operand

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643061/sqlite-db-browser-invalid-operand-for-regexp

Comment: Thanks but no, does not solve issue.

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted, instead of a regexp my boss (smart cookie) suggested I do the following:

```
Update XXXXX
Set height = Case when instr(XXXXXXX,'"height"=>"') > 0
then substr(XXXXXXX,instr(XXXXXXXs,'"height"=>"')+11,instr(substr(XXXXXXX,instr(XXXXXXX,'"height"=>"')+11,5),'"')-1)
else ''
end
```